# The Schwartz function and the sobolev space $W^{2,p}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

How do you prove the Schwartz functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are dense in the space $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

Terrence tao has a version of the proof of

The space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of test function is a dense subspace of $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then the fact $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a corollary from that. I do not understand his proof. (See lemma2)

[enter link description here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/)

Comment: So the proof is already there. Which parts do you not understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Schwartz space contains in particular $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ and $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is by definition dense in $W^{k,p}_0(\mathbb R^n)$. But we have $W^{k,p}_0(\mathbb R^n) = W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$. Thus the Schwartz space is dense in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.

The fact that $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)= W^{k,p}_0(\mathbb R^n)$ can be found in Adam's [Sobolev spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120441438) (Corollary 3.23). The following is part of the proof of Theorem 3.22 in the book.

Let $f : C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ be a smooth function so that $0\le f\le 1$ and

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{ when }|x|\le 1 \\
0 & \text{ when }|x|\ge 2, 
\end{cases}$$

For each $\epsilon >0$, let $f_\epsilon(x) = f(\epsilon x)$. Then all derivatives of $f_\epsilon$ by bounded independent of $\epsilon <1$.

For all $u\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$, consider $u_\epsilon = uf_\epsilon$. Then using the product rule, we have

$$\|u-u_\epsilon\|_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \|u\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega_\epsilon)},$$

where $\Omega_\epsilon = \{x\in \mathbb R^n : |x| \ge 1/\epsilon\}$. As $\epsilon\to 0$, the right hand side converges to $0$. Thus $u $ can be approximated by elements $u_\epsilon$ with compact support. Using mollifiers, this $u_\epsilon$ can be approximated by elements in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$. Thus $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.

In general it is not true that $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega) = W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @ John Ma: why is $W_0^{k,p}=W^{k,p}?$

Comment: @math101 Please see the edit.

Comment: thanks I will need to spend some time on what you wrote, feel free to edit as I go along

Comment: Even for extremely nice domains (e.g. balls), we have $W_0^{k,p}(\Omega) \neq W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @PhoemueX : Thanks. Edited.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding the proof of $C_0^{\infty}$ is dense in $W_0^{k,p}.$ You said that $C_0^{\infty}$ is dense in $W_0^{k,p}.$ by definition. Why? What do you mean by "by definition?

Comment: $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is by definition the $W^{k,p}$-norm closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$. @math101

Comment: I mean $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$

Comment: but the books says, $W_0^{k,p}$ is by definition the closure of $C_0^{\infty}$ in $W^{k,p}.$ Does your first $W^{k,p}$ mean to be $W_0^{k,p}?$

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say: $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. @math101

Comment: You can try Adam's book linked in the answer. @math101

Comment: The proof is exactly as described in Terry's note: As $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n ) \subset S(\mathbb R^n) \subset W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ as $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$, then so is $S(\mathbb R^n)$. (Yes, it's not something new). @math101

Comment: @JohnMa: Why $|x|\ge 1/\epsilon$, why not $dist(x,\partial\Omega)>\epsilon$?

Comment: What is your $\Omega$ in your comment? @math101

Comment: @JohnMa I was looking at a theorem says, if $u\in C(\Omega), \Omega$ bounded and open, satisfies the mean value property, then $u\in C^{\infty}(\Omega).$

Comment: So you are asking a completely different question? @math101

Comment: No, no. I just do not understand how you chosen $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ to be that specific set...

Comment: @JohnMa: Could you please explain how you chose $\Omega_\epsilon = \{x\in \mathbb R^n : |x| \ge 1/\epsilon\}?$ Why $ |x| \ge 1/\epsilon?$

Comment: Note that $u = u_\epsilon$ when $|x| <1/\epsilon$, so $u-u_\epsilon$ has support on $\Omega_\epsilon$. @math101